# How to implement getgrnam_r() in Android NDK? (Does not exist in bionic)

Tags: android, android-ndk

How do I implement this function [getgrnam_r](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getgrnam.3.html) during Android NDK compile ?

```
int getgrnam_r(const char *name, struct group *grp,
                 char *buf, size_t buflen, struct group **result);
```

Comment: You may want to stub this out, since while Android has user groups, they aren't terribly significant beyond a few permissions enforced at that level, ie, there is no /etc/group

Comment: The fact that android doesn't really have meaningful group distinctions between unprivileged apps makes the usage essentially irrelevant - there can't be very many *meaningfully distinct* results from  the function.  We further know, that since the function doesn't exist in bionic, any use of it must be "android ignorant" which will mean that none of the groups which actually exist are relevant.

Comment: So chances are (with the possible exception of one matching the app user id?) you can simply have the implementation always indicate that the requested group doesn't exist - ie return zero and store NULL in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After long times searches :

Implementation №1 : Big thanks to BusyBox guy, who help me (Vladimir N. Oleynik ) : https://gist.github.com/FreakMurderer/d0d770cdb85e5b80a552#file-g-c

Implementation №2 (Another one (I really don't know what better - Try this on your own risk)) : https://github.com/chombourger/android-udev/blob/c78aaf59cdc4378346eb084e9cdc02ca46bc389a/android/missing.c

Comment: What is implicit in these examples of building a getgrnam_r() atop a getgrnam() is the previously overlooked fact that android already provides a getgrnam() and a little checking shows it has since the first NDK release.

Answer (score 1):

Very good question, there has actually be an issue created for this almost **5** years ago(please read here): https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9242

From Google:

> Bionic doesn’t want to implement all features of a traditional C
>   library, we only add features to it as we need them, and we try to
>   keep things as simple and small as possible. Our goal is not to
>   support scaling to thousands of concurrent threads on multi-processors
>   machines; we’re running this on cellphones, damnit !!

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/donut-release/libc/README

Here is more notes on Android's OS and libc(dated 2011): http://cgi.cs.indiana.edu/~nhusted/dokuwiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=wiki:android_project_documentation.pdf

You will notice that `getgrnam_r` is part of the 500+ functions left out of `libc`.

All this being said, there is a repository called `android-busybox`, that implements something very close:

```
/* Search for an entry with a matching group name.  */
struct group* FAST_FUNC getgrnam(const char *__name);
```

Source: https://github.com/sherpya/android-busybox/blob/master/include/grp_.h#L49

Comment: No.  That is a header file containing only a function prototype, not an implementation.  At least link to the implementation: https://github.com/sherpya/android-busybox/blob/master/libpwdgrp/pwd_grp.c  But you would do well to mention that the license terms may make it unusable, in addition to it being unclear if that is even a useful approach.  Also, it is not a "binary" it is a "function".

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am just trying to help point the user in the correct direction. Post your own answer.